# Postgres Partitioning with JPA and migration with Liquibase

Tags: spring-data-jpa, liquibase, database-partitioning

I need to create partitioned table acts, and want to generate migration changelog using liquibase.
How to make JPA entity to be written as  `PARTITION BY list(code)`. And how to manage multicolumn primary key (id, code)?

My entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Table(name = "acts")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class ActEntity extends BaseEntity {

  public static final String GENERATOR_NAME = "acts_gen";
  public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "acts_seq";

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = GENERATOR_NAME)
  @SequenceGenerator(name = GENERATOR_NAME, sequenceName = SEQUENCE_NAME, allocationSize = 1)
  private Long id;

  @PartitionKey
  @Column(name = "code", nullable = false, length = 20)
  private String code;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
  private Boolean status;
}
```